# How can I embed a desktop app (GPT4ALL) into an HTML webUI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, embed, gpt4all, pygpt4all

I'm trying to create a webUI for this desktop app so I can be running it locally from a certain machine, and access through the web for the rest of the company.

I'm very new to this, and I don't know how to work with Python, but I know JS and HTML/CSS.

Is it possible to do this? If someone can give me some pointers I'll really appreciate it.

As I said in the title, the desktop app I need to embed to a webpage is GPT4ALL.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried to use OpenChatKit to create a bot and I've successfully added it to an HTML file and use it running it with Visual Studio Code. It answers back to my questions and I can feed it PDF files or URL links for it to learn, but that's not quite what I need.